# Firestore update array.Union function called with invalid data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have an array of objects; example: `listOfExpenses = [{...}, {...}, {...}]`, currently it's an empty array and I want to add an object to this array.

I call it this way:

```
const chatInstance = db.collection("chats").doc("1234567");

chatInstance.update({
  listOfExpenses: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
    amount: 10,
    category: "food",
    date: "2019-06-16T07:25:26.010Z"
  })
});
```

This is the error I get

```
 FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field listOfExpenses)
      at new FirestoreError (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:355:28)
      at ParseContext.createError (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19726:16)
      at validatePlainObject (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:20111:27)
      at UserDataConverter.parseData (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19912:13)
      at /Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19835:41
      at forEach (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:457:13)
      at UserDataConverter.parseUpdateData (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19826:9)
      at DocumentReference.update (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:20732:52)
      at bot.command.ctx (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/index.js:127:22)
      at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/telegraf/composer.js:128:56)

Failed to process updates. { FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field listOfExpenses)
    at new FirestoreError (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:355:28)
    at ParseContext.createError (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19726:16)
    at validatePlainObject (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:20111:27)
    at UserDataConverter.parseData (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19912:13)
    at /Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19835:41
    at forEach (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:457:13)
    at UserDataConverter.parseUpdateData (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19826:9)
    at DocumentReference.update (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:20732:52)
    at bot.command.ctx (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/index.js:127:22)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/edvinsantonovs/Documents/repos/dollar-dollar-bot/node_modules/telegraf/composer.js:128:56)
  code: 'invalid-argument',
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  toString: [Function] }
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same error it was because my instance of the firebase admin SDK `admin` was not the same as the one I used to get the `firestore()` instance. You might want to try replacing `db` in your example snippet with `admin.firestore()` to make sure this is not the case for you